# vba to count # of clicks on a hyperlink

Tags: vba, excel

I have a tab in a workbook that has over 20 hyperlinks. I want keep track of clicks on a hyperlink to see which hyperlink is utilized the most. so lets say all the hyperlinks are in column "A" so ideally if I click on a hyperlink I want the number of clicks on cell "B". Hoping someone can help. I tried using some formulas but no luck.

below is the code that I am using but doesn't work and there isn't a error message.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink) 
    ThisWorkbook.Activate 
    Selection.Offset(0, 3).FormulaR1C1 = Selection.Offset(0, 3).Value + 1 
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried using VBA yourself? Please show your code thus far, including the areas you are having trouble with. This site is not intended for 'give me code' requests, it is for specific Q&A.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the FollowHyperlink event

The Set up

[image]

The Result when clicking the HyperLink

[image]

This is the code that goes into the worksheet Module

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

    Dim s As Range
    Set s = Target.Range

    s.Offset(0, 1) = s.Offset(0, 1) + 1


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your input!!. Is there a way to do it without naming the hyperlink in the code?